# Is this effect because of the lenses? what type?

Tags: lens, focal-length

https://www.instagram.com/p/CwsKDthOdST
So in this video, the legs of the man look really small. I thought at first it must be because of the lenses but if it were for wide angle lenses, that would increase the volume of the things in the center. His legs are in the center but they look shrunken. How?

[image]

Comment: Post a screen capture, please. Not a link to a random video.

Comment: Hi. Please edit the title of your question to describe the question, as best you can, in one sentence. "Is this effect...?" can apply to any question about some sort of "effect". Additionally, please edit your post to include a screen capture or single frame of the video; some users cannot access IG videos. And if the original IG goes away, with a screenshot this question won't become stale with a dead link. Thank you! =)

Comment: It looks to me like it was taken with a wide angle lens and then the image adjusted to be rectilinear. So the answer would be that the image was distorted by software.